# Express.js - I can't set the Content-Type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Express.js, and I can't set the Content-Type header for some reason. I set it to `text/html` and it sends with `application/octet-stream` anyway. Here is my code:

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

const fs = require("fs")

const Template = require("./Template")

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.type("html")
    res.send(String(Template.solidify(fs.readFileSync("index.html"))))
})

app.listen(80, () => {
    console.log("Listening...")
})
```

`Template.solidify()` just returns what it's given for now. index.html is an empty html file (with head, body, etc.).

Comment: have you debugged what the value is or if its happeing with only `res.send('test')`? Why not use `app.engine('html', Template.solidify); app.set('view engine', 'html')`, then do `res.render('index', {})` etc?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just had to clear my cache

Comment: app.disable('etag')

Answer (score 1):

Update for anybody looking for answers, I just had to clear my browser cache.

I use chrome, and I was able to disable cache while devtools is open by checking the box.